# How to create a sequence of two values?

Tags: python

I have a list with different combinations, i.e:

```
list1 = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
```

I also have another list, in my case one looking like:

```
list2 = [1,1]
```

What I would like to do is to take the two values of `list2`, put them together as `(1,1)`, and compare them with the elements in `list1`, then returning the index. My current attempt is looking like this:

```
def return_index(comb):
    try:
         return comb_leaves.index(comb)
    except ValueError:
         print("no such value")
```

Unfortunately, it cant find it, because it's not a sequence. Anyone with any good idea of how to fix this?

Comment: What is the error, what is not a sequence?

Comment: convert list2 to a tuple then use index, `tuple(list2)`

Comment: `list1.index(tuple(list2))`???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are confusing "sequence" with "tuple". Lists and tuples are both sequences. Informally, a sequence is anything that has a length and supports direct indexing in addition to being iterable. A `range` object is considered to be a sequence too for example.

To create a two element tuple from any other sequence, use the constructor:

```
test_element = tuple(list_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list3 = tuple(list2)
print(list3 in list1) #Check if it exists.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
list2 = [1,1]

tup2 = tuple(list2)

list1.append(tup2)
print('list1:',list1)

print('index:', list1.index(tup2))
```

will give this:

```
list1: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (1, 1)]
index: 4
```

Not sure if unconditionally adding `tup2` is what you want.

Maybe you ask for the index, if the 2nd list is in list1:

```
list1 = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]list2 = [1,1]

tup2 = tuple(list2)
if tup2 in list1:
    print('index:', list1.index(tup2))
else:
    print('not found')
```

That gives:

```
index: 4
```

the `index` function returns the first element that matches.

Comment: Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission; `try`-`except` is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
list1 = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2)]
list2 = [1, 1]

def return_index(comb):
    try:
        return list1.index(tuple(comb))
    except ValueError:
        print("Item not found")

print(return_index(list2)) # 4
```

With this line:

```
list1.index(tuple(list2))
```

Convert `list2` into a `tuple` from a `list`. `list1`'s elements are tuples, so to make the comparison, `list2` needs to be a `tuple`. `tuple(list2)` turns `[1, 1]` into `(1, 1)` (the same type as the elements of `list1`).